# a function that gets a function pointer and a class pointer?

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I want to make the `MapIf` function in a class called Map. `MapIf` will be called like this:

```
void addThree(int& n) {
    n += 3;
}

class startsWith {
    char val;

public:

    startsWith(char v) : val(v) {};

    bool operator()(const std::string& str) {
        return str.length() && char(str[0]) == val;
    }
};

int main(){
...
    startsWith startWithB('B');

    Map<std::string, int> msi;

    MapIf(msi, startWithB, addThree);
    return 0;
}
```

---

What would be the declaration of `MapIf` ?

```
void MapIf(const Map& map, class condition, void (*function)(ValueType));
```

is this ok ?

Comment: I wonder how come you know what the function call looks like but not the function prototype.

Comment: Is Map as in std::map (associative container) or as in map-reduce? (Perform an operation on every element in the sequence).

Could be both here as you are looking if a key has a predicate and then operating on its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should match your prototype.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Condition>
void MapIf(const Map<Key, Value>& map, Condition condition, void (*function)(Value&));
```

Comment: Yeah, when in doubt just template all the parameters and let the compiler work out what you actually want...

In the case of Condition though I agree that has to be a templated parameter.

Comment: Why would you template every argument? That would be very prone to awkward bugs; e.g. the function could be called with anything, but you'd end up with cryptic error messages when the function body is compiled.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield: OP didn't provide `Map`, `ValueType`. So instead of using magic ball, I provide a correct (vague) answer. No we have more info, I restrict my prototype.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield your argument is really why they wanted to introduce "concepts" into templated programming, so you would get an error at the point of template misuse rather than in the template itself. However they never actually worked out how it would work properly within the standard so it wasn't included.

Answer (score 0):

Rather

```
void MapIf(const Map& map, startsWith condition, void (*addThree)(int));
```

Comment: Naming the function pointer `addThree` is confusing. The `MapIf` function could presumably be used with any function pointer matching the correct signature (i.e. not just the `addThree` example in the question).

Answer (score 0):

It looks as you want to have multiple conditions and all conditions are [function objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional).
I could suggest you to use std::function for condition. In this case you could use this class and other classes and other functions and even lambdas;

```
MapIf(Map<std::string, int>& map, std::function<bool(const std::string&)> condition, std::function<void(int&)> callback);
```

in this case you could call this function in this ways:

```
MapIf(msi, startWithB, addThree);

MapIf(msi, [](const string& str)->bool{return str.length() % 2 = 0}, addThree);

MapIf(msi, startWithA, [](int& val){val-=2});
```

You could use templates to make it more generic of course.

Comment: Why would you accept a `std::function` object here? Accept a Functor through a template. The purpose of `std::function` is not to make function pointer declarations easier to read, but to provide type erasure over callable objects. It is almost never necessary to expose this to the caller.